# Missing template in SyliusSettingsBundle

Tags: symfony, sylius

Installed `sylius/settings-bundle` 0.17.0 on my symfony 2.8.3 application, followed [official instructions](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusSettingsBundle/installation.html) to register bundles in AppKernel and update config.yml/routing.yml.

But when trying to access the config page's URL defined in routing, I get the following error **Unable to find template "SyliusSettingsBundle:Settings:update.html.twig"**. I also tried looking in the bundle's files but couldn't find any `update.html.twig` anywhere.

Any idea what else I could do to resolve that one?